# Como colocar borda em link sem aumentar tamanho de menu

Tags: css

Tenho um menu, e queria que ao colocasse o mouse em cima o link tivesse uma borda, eu consegui colocar, porem o problema é que ele aumenta o tamanho do menu quando a borda aparece, como evitar isto ?

[image: Normal]
[image: Com Hover]

Código Atual:

```
    .main-nav-outer{
    padding:0px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #dddddd;
    box-shadow:0 4px 5px -3px #ececec;
    position:relative;
    background:#fff;
}
.main-nav{
    text-align:center;
    margin:3px 0 0px;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    max-height: 75px;
}
.main-nav li{
    display:inline;
    margin:0 1px;
}
.main-nav li a{
    display:inline-block;
    color:#222222;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    line-height:20px;
    margin:17px 32px;
    transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.main-nav li a:hover{
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #154372;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #154372;
}
```

Comment: Você pode apenas aplicar uma borda transparente e quando o mouse passar por cima aplique a cor desejada.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### `box-sizing`

Há uma propriedade que controla isto, o `box-sizing`:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Quando usado conforme a linha acima, faz com que a medida do elemento inclua a borda. Em outras palavras, com `border-box` a espessura será descontada do conteúdo e não do entorno.

### `outline`

Alternativamente você pode usar o `outline` no lugar do `border`. O `outline` é um elemento visual que não afeta *layout*:

> Compatibilidade: https://caniuse.com/#search=outline

Cabe ao *designer* analisar qual é mais adequado para o seu caso específico, observada a diferença de comportamento em relação ao conteúdo e aos espaçamentos.

### Demonstração

**box-sizing:**

```css
div    { display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;
         width:100px;height:60px; background-color:#fcc;
         text-align:center; }

#b, #c { border:4px solid black; }
#b     { box-sizing:border-box; }
```

```html
<div id="a">sem borda</div>
<div id="b">border-box</div>
<div id="c">padrão</div>
<div id="d">sem borda</div>
```

**outline:**

```css
div    { display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;
         width:100px;height:60px; background-color:#fcc;
         text-align:center; }

#b, #c { outline:4px solid black; }
#c     { outline-offset:-4px; }
```

```html
<div id="a">sem outline</div>
<div id="b">com outline</div>
<div id="c">outline<br>com offset</div>
<div id="d">sem outline</div>
```

Comment: Tentei das duas formas,  a do box-sizing: border-box nao alterou nada, continuo da mesma forma, e o outline fez a mesma coisa, devo esta fazendo algo errado, aonde deve ir o box sizing?

Comment: @IgorOliveira dificil dizer sem ver o HTML. O ideal é por no elemento de bloco que compõe os itens do menu. Provavelmente algo que tenha `display:block` ou `display:inline-block` (no seu caso o correto parece ser o `.main-nav li a { box-sizing:border-box; ...` - atenção à grafia.

Answer (score 0):

Exitem mais duas opções que podem e atender uma com `box-shadow` e outra com `calc()` descontando do `height` e `width` a espessura da borda.

**Opção 1:** Usando `box-shadow` com `inset` e `spread-radius` inclusive com essa técnica é possível fazer várias bordas para dentro e para fora do elemento sem afetar nada que está em volta!

**OBS:** `spread-radius` é o quarto parâmetro do propriedade, ele é opcional e vc pode não usa-lo sempre. Coloquei entre <kbd>" 4px "</kbd> apenas para vc vizualisar melhor.

```
/* offset-x | offset-y | blur-radius | spread-radius | color */
box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px " 4px " rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
```

**Veja o exemplo abaixo, usei como base o modelo do nosso amigo @Bacco que está bem didático.**

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 0;
}
div { 
    display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;
    width:120px;height:60px; background-color:#fcc;
    text-align:center; 
}
#a { box-shadow: 0 0 4px black inset; }
#b, #c { box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px black;}
#c { box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px black inset; }
#e { box-shadow: 0 0 4px black inset, 0 0 0 4px black, 0 0 0 6px red, 0 0 0 8px lime, 0 0 0 10px purple;}
```

```html
<div id="a">box-shadow inset sem "spread-radius"</div>
<div id="b">com box-shadow</div>
<div id="c">box-shadow inset com "spread-radius"</div>
<div id="d">sem box-shadow</div>
<div id="e">várias box-shadow e 1 inset</div>
```

Aqui vc pode ler mais sobre a propriedade `box-shadow`: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow

---

**Opção 2:** Nessa técnica vc vai centralizar o conteúdo das DIVs com `Flex-Box` e depois colocar a Bordar no `:hover` porém descontando a largura da borda da altura e da largura da Div

**Ex:** Se vc tem uma borda de 4px vc vai ter que abater 8px da altura e da largura da DIV, 8px pois são 4px de cada lado, logo temos 8px

```
div:hover {
    border: 4px solid black;
    width:calc(120px - 8px);
    height:calc(60px - 8px); 
}
```

**Veja no Exemplo abaixo a técnica aplicada**

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 0;
}
div { 
    background-color:#fcc;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin: 2px;
    width:120px;
    height:60px; 
}
div:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 4px solid black;
}
div.calc:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 4px solid black;
    width:calc(120px - 8px);
    height:calc(60px - 8px); 
}
```

```html
<section style="display: flex;flex-direction: row;">
    <div class="calc">COM calc()</div>
    <div class="calc">COM calc()</div>
    <div>SEM calc()</div>
    <div>SEM calc()</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma outra maneira é usando o *pseudo-elemento* `::after` oculto que só irá aparecer no `:hover`.

Então você inclui uma borda no `::after` e dimensiona ele com menos 2px do total das dimensões do botão. Com isso não afetará o tamanho do menu.

Veja o exemplo de como ficaria:

```css
body{
   background: #000;
}

.main-nav{
    text-align:center;
    margin:3px 0 0px;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    xmax-height: 75px;
    background: #fff;
    min-height: 74px;
}

.main-nav li{
    display:inline;
    margin:0 1px;
}

.main-nav li a{
    display:inline-block;
    color:#222222;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    line-height:20px;
    margin:17px 32px;
    transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    position: relative;
}

.main-nav li a:hover{
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #154372;
}

.main-nav li a:hover::after{
    display: block;
}

.main-nav li a::after{
   content: '';
   width: calc(100% - 2px);
   height: calc(100% - 2px);
   border: 1px solid #154372;
   border-radius: 3px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main-nav">
   <li><a href="#">Botão 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Botão 2</a></li>
</ul>
```